# Split a long line in Python without \

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a line of code in python that is way too long. I'm trying to format it, but my company doesn't allow the use of "\" to break lines. 
I tried it as such,

```
(subject, message, chatRoomMsg, chatRecipientMsg) = 
  set_mail_and_chat(user, user_dict[user])
```

How can I format this line to make it work, but also keep the line under 80 characters.

Comment: Couldn't you make `(subject, message, chatRoomMsg, chatRecipientMsg)` a named tuple?

Answer (score 6):

Split it into two:

```
result = set_mail_and_chat(user, user_dict[user])
subject, message, chatRoomMsg, chatRecipientMsg = result
```

Comment: The rationale behind not allowing \ is probably the idea that as many statements as possible should be in a single line (which definitely increases legibility). This answer meets this criterion best.

Answer (score 6):

You can leave the opening parenthesis in the first line, and continue in the second one:

```
subject, message, chatRoomMsg, chatRecipientMsg = (
    set_mail_and_chat(user, user_dict[user]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Starting  the second line with `) =` is valid.

```
(subject, message, chatRoomMsg, chatRecipientMsg
 ) = set_mail_and_chat(user, user_dict[user])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leave the opening parenthesis of function parameters in the first line,

```
(subject, message, chatRoomMsg, chatRecipientMsg)= set_mail_and_chat(
    user, user_dict[user])
```

Check the [style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more information.